# something stopped me in winJS

Tags: winjs

I want to implement a feature in winJS:
1. Load any web with url in any size;
2.scroll to any position in this web;
3.after I scroll to the potision I need, set the web cannot be scrolled. Only display the specified area of the web.

How can I solve this problem and go to next step?

Comment: Can you provide better details about the use-case?

e.g.
Are you attempting to navigate to an external web address from within the app's window context? 
Are you talking about Win10 Web Apps (where the app itself is a container that loads an external endpoint on launch)?

Can you also separate out the two issues in terms of details? (Load vs Viewport Sizing)

Comment: can you share what have you tried so far? what stopped you?